# Get last record from each different id

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm trying to retrieve data from my table. Here is how it is build

```
 id | room |  user  |    date    | comment
  1    1       22      2289248      hello
  2    2       33      2489298      thanks
  3    1       17      2489300      ok
  4    2       18      2490000      good
```

then what I try to retrieve is the last entry made in each room based on the date then the result I'm looking for should look like this

```
3 | 1 | 17 | 2489300 | ok
4 | 2 | 18 | 2490000 | good
```

Comment: Does the table have a primary key or any field that is unique across all rows?

Comment: yes sorry it have id column that is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order them first, then group them:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY date DESC) t GROUP BY room`

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6be7f4/1)

Comment: hi this return what i got at this time it return the first entry of each room but i need the last entry

Comment: Are you sure you commented on the right answer? It shows exactly the data you requested.

Comment: sorry my bad i was looking at data wrong way that is good it show it as it should thank you very much

Comment: @rjdown rmay i know what is this kind of queries called the select statement  inside another select statement

Comment: @Ahmadghoneim it's called a subquery